# json parsing in bash using sed regex expression

Tags: regex, sed

I was wondering if somebody could help me with this sed regex expression.

```
{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_arguments","response_metadata":{"messages":["[ERROR] missing required field: channel "]}}
```

From the following json, I need to extract the value corresponding to ok. Here it is `false`.

To do this, I use the `sed -n '/"ok":[\w]*/p'` regex but it doesn't work..

I'm new the sed and regex expression.. Is there somebody to help me??

Comment: `sed -E 's/\{"ok":([a-zA-Z]+),.*/\1/' file`

Comment: Wow.. It works.. I'll study from now on. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I've posted this as an answer @Ga.R, if this has solution has worked for you, then you can upvote n accept it as an answer...happy learning :-)

Comment: Your attempt would simply print the entire line if it contains `"ok":` anywhere, except `sed` typically does not support the `\w` escape, so it was probably interpreted as a literal `w` and so the expression was not found.

Comment: @User123 Thank you for answering! I want to upvote you, but my reputation is not enough.. 
I'll increase my repuation and come back soon :)

Comment: @tripleee
Yes, I think you're right.. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^\{"ok":([a-zA-Z]+),.*/\1/' file
```

***Explanation***:

```
-E              :: Use extended regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions
^\{"ok":        :: search for the string starting with: {"ok":
([a-zA-Z]+),.*  :: to capture the desired group using (), here ,the string: *false*
\1              :: backreference to print/output the captured group
```